# Mod wsgi not using virtualenv python version on Arch linux

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a website running on apache-python2(virtualenv)-flask stack on Arch linux server. It seems that wsgi application is not picking up the python from virtualenv, and instead uses system's python.

**web/test.py**

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Result in: `error_log`

```
3.4.3 (default, Mar 25 2015, 17:13:50)
```

The default python on the server is

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

The virtual environment I intend to use has python2

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 flask
$ source flask/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

The virtualhost apache file:
**/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/msw.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName msw.com
    ServerAlias www.msw.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    WSGIDaemonProcess msw user=live group=live threads=5 python-path=/home/live/msw/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/live/msw/msw.wsgi

    <Directory /home/live/msw>
            #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            WSGIProcessGroup msw
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIPassAuthorization On
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The wsgi file:
**/home/live/msw/msw.wsgi**

```
import sys

activate_this = '/home/live/msw/flask/bin/activate_this.py'
#execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), activate_this, 'exec')
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))

    sys.path.insert(0, '/home/live/msw/web')
    sys.path.insert(0, '/home/live/msw')

    from web import msw as application
```

Why is mod_wsgi not picking up virtualenv's python? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install mod_wsgi? It needs to be compiled against the version of Python you want to use.

Comment: @dirn - Yea, I eventually figured that out. What confused me was official arch-linux documentation, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mod_wsgi#Installation. It tries to imply that mod_wsgi installation will work for both Python2/3. But it still uses system's Python3. Problem solved by installing `pacman -S mod_wsgi2` which is specific to Python2.

Comment: Thanks so much @Neo this fixed my problem too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. The official arch-linux documentation is a bit confusing,  [mod_wsgi](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mod_wsgi#Installation). It tries to imply that mod_wsgi installation will work for both Python2/3. However, mod_wsgi still ends up using system's Python3. I solved the problem by installing mod_wsgi2 which is specific to Python2.

```
pacman -S mod_wsgi2
```